# How can the timeout time be logged when using wait.until with selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow, webdriverwait

Currently I am using the the following **wait.until** code:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id<locator>));
```

I want to be able to identify the scenarios when this code takes the longest time. I am using this code in multiple places but is there a way that I can log the timeout through selenium without adding a stopwatch before / after this code is invoked?

Comment: You set the timeout. Are you asking about the scenario where you set the timeout to  30s and it gets done at 15s and you want to log 15 or ? Please add an example because right now it's hard to tell what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Best approach I have come up with is an extension method:

```
    public static IWebElement LoggedUntil(this WebDriverWait wait, Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> condition)
    {
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

        try
        {
            return wait.Until(condition);
        }
        finally
        {
            watch.Stop();
            var elapsedSeconds = watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
            Console.WriteLine($"Wait took: {elapsedSeconds} Seconds");
        }
    }
```

After this I can then changed all references that use **.Until** to use **.LoggedUntil**

```
   protected IWebElement FindElement(By by)
   {
        Console.WriteLine($"Find {by}");
        return Wait.LoggedUntil(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(by));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't measure the *timeout* but you configure the **TimeOut**.

[WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) in conjunction with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) is induced to wait for the desired element either to be:

- `present`
- `visibe`
- `interactable`

The constructors of [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) Class are:

- [WebDriverWait Constructor (IWebDriver, TimeSpan)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait__ctor.htm) which is defind as:

  ```
  public WebDriverWait(
      IWebDriver driver,
      TimeSpan timeout
  )

  Parameters:
  driver
      Type: OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver
      The WebDriver instance used to wait.
  timeout
      Type: System.TimeSpan
      The timeout value indicating how long to wait for the condition.
  ```
- [WebDriverWait Constructor (IClock, IWebDriver, TimeSpan, TimeSpan)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait__ctor_1.htm) which is defind as:

  ```
  public WebDriverWait(
      IClock clock,
      IWebDriver driver,
      TimeSpan timeout,
      TimeSpan sleepInterval
  )

  Parameters
  clock
      Type: OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.IClock
      An object implementing the IClock interface used to determine when time has passed.
  driver
      Type: OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver
      The WebDriver instance used to wait.
  timeout
      Type: System.TimeSpan
      The timeout value indicating how long to wait for the condition.
  sleepInterval
      Type: System.TimeSpan
      A TimeSpan value indicating how often to check for the condition to be true.
  ```

The *timeout* and *sleepInterval* are pretty much configurable and should be configured as per the *Test Specifications* as the desired elements needs to be *present*, *visibe* or *interactable* within the desired **timespan**.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to extension methods you can create a class that implements `IWait<IWebDriver>` to bake in the timing and logging of the duration.

The WebDriverWait class inherits from DefaultWait, which implements the IWait interface (IWait to be exact). You can nest "wait" objects. The "wait" object that measure the duration just needs to implement the IWait interface:

```
public class TimeableWebDriverWait : IWait<IWebDriver>
{
    private readonly Action<string> logger;
    private readonly IWait<IWebDriver> wait;

    public string Message
    {
        get => wait.Message;
        set => wait.Message = value;
    }

    public TimeSpan PollingInterval
    {
        get => wait.PollingInterval;
        set => wait.PollingInterval = value;
    }

    public TimeSpan Timeout
    {
        get => wait.Timeout;
        set => wait.Timeout = value;
    }

    public TimeableWebDriverWait(IWait<IWebDriver> wait, Action<string> logger = null)
    {
        this.wait = wait ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(wait));
        this.logger = logger ?? Console.WriteLine;
    }

    public void IgnoreExceptionTypes(params Type[] exceptionTypes)
    {
        wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(exceptionTypes);
    }

    public TResult Until<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> condition)
    {
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

        try
        {
            return wait.Until<TResult>(condition);
        }
        finally
        {
            watch.Stop();

            logger($"Wait took: {watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} Seconds");
        }
    }
}
```

And now you can use it with *any* WebDriverWait object:

```
var realWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
var wait = new TimeableWebDriverWait(realWait);

wait.Until(...);
```

You can specify your own function to log the message, as long as it accepts a string parameter and has a `void` return type:

```
var realWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
var wait = new TimeableWebDriverWait(realWait, System.Diagnostic.Trace.WriteLine);

wait.Until(...);
```